# concat and insert using php using quotes

Tags: php, sql, yii

I want to add quotes to `$sdatetime`, so i can insert `('2013-12-1217:15:15')` something like this into db. How do I go about it?

**form --**

```
<input size="16" type="text" name="sday">
<input type="text" name="stime" size="16">
```

**function ---**

```
$sdatetime=$_POST["sday"].$_POST["stime"];
$model->start_date=$sdatetime;
```

Comment: Your model should handle that for you. However you need a space in between the date and time: `$sdatetime=$_POST["sday"] . " " . $_POST["stime"];`. so that your date string is `2013-12-12 17:15:15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sdatetime = $_POST["sday"]." ".$_POST["stime"]; //OP - 2013-12-12 17:15:15
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use plain PHP, you can benefit from [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$sdatetime = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sday"].$_POST["stime"]);
```

This makes sure everything is fine with the data you insert (meaning that, it won't be subject to SQL injection).

Maybe you'll want to use the `MySQLi` PHP extension, as it's more up to date;  [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) will help you then.

As a side note, having a model there should help you make your queries. You should read more on the model documentation of the framework you are using. Also, there are better ways of reading a datetime from user input and saving it properly to the database.

Comment: @Andrei Horak : Im using Yii so the quotes were not needed. Thanks for the detailed answer btw. I'll use it while using plain PHP.

Comment: Well, you asked for quotes and I've given an answer based on your request. Apparently you have accepted an answer which does not relate directly to your question :)

Comment: @AndreiHorak It was mentioned in my tags. The answer above resolved my query hence, I selected that. Sorry. Thanks though. :)

Comment: No problem, glad you could find an answer here :)